# Google OAuth2 verification hangs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I am trying to write a Google Chrome extension that will replace the new tab page and can connect to a users Google Calendar to show upcoming events. I am having trouble getting the extension to properly authorize access with OAuth.

I am testing the following code to authorize the user:

func.js

```
// initialize google api
gapi.client.setApiKey('MY API KEY');
gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    console.log('calendar api loaded')
});

// OAuth2 verification
function auth() {
  var config = {
    'client_id': 'MY CLIENT ID',
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
  };
  gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
    console.log('login complete');
    console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
  });
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
    // ...
    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "MY CLIENT_ID",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
        ]
    },
    // ...
}
```

The Google API is initialized properly and the callback function is called. Before I added the `"oauth2"` parameter to `manifest.json`, I received an error from Google, but now when `auth()` is called the authentication popup window appears, but it just stays blank and says 'connecting' and nothing ever shows. Am I doing OAuth verification correctly? What is causing this hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add `'immediate': true` inside `var config`